# How can I run code in a C# class definition each time any instance of the class is deserialized?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I am trying to derive a class from ObservableCollection and I need to run just a single line of code each and every time any instance of this class is deserialized.  My thought was to do this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ObservableCollection2<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ISerializable
{
    public ObservableCollection2()
        : base()
    { }

    public ObservableCollection2(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        // Put additional code here.
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```

But I don't have access to those base methods related to serialization.  Am I forced to re-write all of the serialization manually?

Comment: You should really indicate *how* you are serializing; there are multiple inbuilt and 3rd party serialization APIs, and they each support different patterns / usage.

Comment: Good point.  I am using the built-in .NET binary serialization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`OnDeserializedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx): "When applied to a method, specifies that the method is called immediately after deserialization of the object." Note that the method also needs to accept a [`StreamingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.aspx) parameter:

```
[Serializable]
public class ObservableCollection2<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
{
    [OnDeserialized()]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.DateDeserialized = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer but an example with a few lines wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! (P.S. You should remove ISerializable)

Comment: You mean it's one-line easy? How dare they! I thought everything was supposed to be hard and arcane so that the people dumber than me couldn't even begin to write code. Obviously, if you make things easy, normal people might want to write code.</sarcasm>